# Integrals using Arctangens

Tags: integration

We want to find $\displaystyle \int\dfrac{12}{16x^2 +1}$

I rewrote it to the form $ 3 \cdot \dfrac{1}{u^2 + 1} \cdot u' $ where $u=4x$.

I found out that the correction sheet does the same thing, but their next step leaves my puzzled:

$$ F(x) = 3 \arctan (4x) + C$$

Where did the $u' = 4$ go to?

Comment: Try differentiating $3\arctan(4x)$ and I think you'll see everything is in order.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, but it still won't clear my confusion on why the 4 dissapears. I might convince me that the answer is correct, but that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: @GerryMyerson I followed your suggestion, and I still don't know why you can just make the $u'$ disappear

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are asking, but the $u'=4$ combined with the $3$ in your second sentence to give the 12 in your first sentence. Or, rather, the $4$ in $12=3\times4$ got absorbed into the $u'$, leaving just the $3$. Maybe it would be clearer if you wrote the integrand with numerator $12\,dx$ and then you'd have $3\,du=12\,dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, if $u = 4x$, then $du = 4dx$, yielding
$$\begin{split}
\int \frac{12dx}{16x^2+1} 
 &= 3 \int \frac{4dx}{(4x)^2+1} \\
 &= 3 \int \frac{u'dx}{(u)^2+1} \\
 &= 3 \int \frac{du}{u^2+1} \\
 &= 3 \arctan(u) + C \\
 &= 3 \arctan(4x)+C
\end{split}
$$

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question

Comment: @ArcTan what is the question: $4dx \to du$ and then you take the integral with respect to $u$ and substitute back.

Perhaps I don't understand the question - could you please make it more clear?

Comment: In my calculation, why does the $u' = 4$ disappear?

Comment: @ArcTan Because for $u=u(x)$, you get $u'(x)dx = du$ and so when you convert $\int \frac{4dx}{(4x)^2+1}$ to the one in terms of $u$, the numerator gets converted as $4dx = u'dx = du$. It is pure substition, just like the denominator, except you have to make sure there are no $dx$ anywhere in the resulting integral - it all must be in terms of $u$.

Comment: @ArcTan I inserted an extra step in the above answer to show this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It went to the composite function $arctan \circ u$ when it obtained by integrating $arctan'(u(x))u'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If substitution is to be done successfully, it is a good idea to use standard notation, which was designed to make the work mechanical. The OP starts with "We want to find $\int \frac{12}{16x^2+1}$." That is **not** notationally correct. The use of incorrect notation may be part of the reason you find the subsitution problematic.

What we want to find is
$$\int \frac{12}{16x^2+1}\,dx.$$
Now we will go through the substitution process *mechanically*. Let $u=4x$.

We need to replace $x$ *everywhere* by the appropriate expression that involves $u$. From $u=4x$, we obtain $\frac{du}{dx}=4$. Write this as $du=4\,dx$, and then as 
$$dx=\frac{1}{4}\,du.$$
Now do the substitution. We must replace the $dx$ by the appropriate expression that only inovlves $u$. We get
$$\int \frac{12}{u^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\,du.$$
There is a bit of numerical cancellation. We get
$$\int\frac{3}{u^2+1}\,du.$$
This is a familiar integral, and the result is 
$$3\arctan u+C.$$
Finally, replace the $u$ by $4x$.

**Remark:** Leaving out the "$dx$" may sound like a nice time (and paper) saving step. But it tends to lead to wrong answers.